# Inflation calculation

Tags: inflation

Am I correct in saying that £100 in the year 2000 was worth roughly £60 in 2018 (or had the same buying power to put it another way)?

I've used the calculator [here](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/monetary-policy/inflation/inflation-calculator), but they way they put it is slightly different  to the way I'd like to word it and I just wanted to make sure I wasn't misinterpreting the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to talk about inflation is to show numbers rising, e.g. What cost me $100 in 1976 would have cost $446 in 2018.

The way you are phrasing the question is fine, however. The hundred dollar I had in 1976, just left on my night table, would buy $21.59 worth of goods.

Both direction work depending on your goal. Strangely enough, electronics' cost has gone in the other direction, over time most consumer electronics become more powerful at a rate far faster than any price increase due to inflation. But, I digress.

Answer (score 2):

No, the other way around. What you could buy for £60 in 2000 you would now need £100 to buy.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing? If bought £60 of stuff in 2000, that same stuff would cost me £100 now. Same as saying buying £100 of stuff in 1000 will have depreciated in value to about £60 now. It's a bit of a word game too, but I think we're saying the same thing?

Comment: I see what you are saying now, but I think your original phrasing is poor. £100 in 2000 had *more* buying power than £60 did in 2018. What you could say is if you had £100 in 2000, and held onto it until 2018, you would only be able to buy £60 (but this is year-2000 pounds) worth of stuff. £100 in 2018 will always buy you £100 (in year-2018 pounds) worth of stuff.

Comment: Your perspective perhaps makes the most sense looking forward. If I have £100 now, and I hold onto it for X years, how much will it be worth *in today's pounds*?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's as clear as I'd have liked. Thanks for the suggestion :)